# Is SQL Connection path for this ErrMsg System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

Newbie here.

It has been quite some time, could not remember the whole process of installation the SQL Server 2008 / 2008 R2.

These are the instances I found on the C: drive:

- in `Program Files(x86)`, I have

  - `MSSQL10_50.DEVSQLEXPRESS`
- in `Program files`, I have

  - `MSSQL10.DEVSQLEXPRESS2`
  - `MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER`

I use SSMS to connect the SQL Server instances with Windows authentication

Somehow, `DEVSQLEXPRESS` does not show up in SSMS (from SQL Server 2008 R2) and I can not delete it.

`DEVSQLEXPRESS2` can be connected in SSMS. Now I am using `DEVSQLEXPRESS2` for Asp.net Web Api for testing purpose.

This is my code. No compilation error.

```
public User Add(User contact)
{
    try
    {               
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source= .\\DEVSQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=MyBookingHub;Integrated Security=true");

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (UserName,UserPassword,UserEmailAddr,UserMobile) 
Values (@UserName,@UserPassword,@UserEmailAddr,@UserMobile)";

        sqlCmd.Connection = conn;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", contact.UserName);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", contact.UserPassword);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmailAddr", contact.UserEmailAddr);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserMobileNo", contact.UserMobileNo);

         conn.Open();

         int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         conn.Close();

         var ctc = new User()
         {
             UserId = rowInserted,
             UserName = contact.UserName,
             UserPassword = contact.UserPassword,
             UserEmailAddr =contact.UserEmailAddr,
             UserMobileNo = contact.UserMobileNo
          };

          return ctc;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          string err = ex.ToString();
          return null;   
      }
 }
```

This the problem encountered:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ' '.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at MyBookingService.DataAccessModelRepository.UserRepository.Add(User contact) in C:\Users\Edward\Documents\Visual Studio 2015__AspNet_Web_Api\MyBookingService\MyBookingService\DataAccessModelRepository\UserRepository.cs:line 82
>
> ClientConnectionId:65379b7b-f681-459c-b98f-99e55d09fdcc
>   Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15

**update:**

Table in SQL Server:

```
UserId        int
UserName      nvarchar(30)
UserPassword  nvarchar(30)
UserEmailAddr nvarchar(120)
UserMobileNo  nvarchar(20)
CreatedOn     datetime     //Allow Null

//- use SqlDbType
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = contact.UserName;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = contact.UserPassword;

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserEmailAddr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 120).Value = contact.UserEmailAddr;

sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserMobileNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = contact.UserMobileNo;
```

Result is still the same as before

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Please refer to the latest update. The result is the same. Is my Sql Connection correct? Is my Sql Instance OK? I am not sure.

Comment: I think I know the problem. 1) UserMobile should be UserMobileNo 2) I Posted 5 parameters, the last one is date and I only handled 4 parameters. Thanks for your Tip on Stop using AddWithValue()